# Detected a mismatch for the compiler version between your conan profile settings and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, conan

I had an issue with CMake who were not detecting the right version of the CMake compiler.

My CMake was working with the command line but not in CLion.

Here the output log from the CMake tool in CLion:

```
CMake Error at build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:1344 (message): Detected a mismatch for the compiler version between your conan profile settings and CMake: Compiler version specified in your conan profile: 9 Compiler version detected in CMake: 8.3 Please check your conan profile settings (conan profile show [default|your_profile_name])
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem, including **specific** error logs, the actual commands or build steps to reproduce the issue, and relevant environment details.

Comment: You can read about CLion integration here: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/ide/clion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to change the two path for compilation:

Press `CTRL + ALT + S` to open the parameters

Go to `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Toolchain`

Switch `C Compiler` to `/usr/bin/gcc` and `C++ Compiler` to `/usr/bin/g++`